# A strange layout by using aspect-ratio in flexbox

Tags: flexbox, aspect-ratio

The **dl** is flexbox, **dd** is a box of some content.

The **dt** is expected the same height with **dd**, and its content width is equal to it height.

---

A strange result is when the page first loaded, the width of **dt** isn't correct.

But it works well after a reflow. Happened both in Chrome and Firefox.

I don't know whether it's a browser bug or usage incorrect.

```css
section {
 display: inline-block;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

dl {
 display: flex;
 gap: 0 5px;
 background: #ddd;
 border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
 padding-right: 10px;
 margin: 0;
}
dt {
 flex: 0 0 auto;
 width: fit-content;
}
dd {
 margin: 0;
 flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.tag {
 height: 100%;
 background: #0ff;
 aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <dl>
  <dt>
   <div class="tag">Test1</div>
  </dt>
  <dd>
   <p>Description 11111</p>
   <p>Description 22222</p>
  </dd>
 </dl>
</section>

<section>
 <dl>
  <dt>
   <div class="tag">Test2</div>
  </dt>
  <dd>
   <p>Description 11111</p>
  </dd>
 </dl>
</section>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Woody-lxf/pen/jOZMqEJ)

Comment: I can't seem to recreate this width glitch, can you please explain more what I should be looking for by editing your question

Comment: @ZachJensz The width of .tag element isn't fit to its child element on loaded. But try to reflow it, such as change opacity, the width is fitted to its child.